# Website CSS - Left Bar Doesn't Expand Past Scroll in Window

Tags: html, css

Hopefully my title isn't too confusing.  I have a webpage that has a .main div with a .left div beside it.

When I add content to .main it expands past the window, adding a scroll bar.  My problem is that when I scroll down the background for the .left div doesn't continue past the original window height.

I know similar questions have been asked many times but I can't seem to fit any of the solutions into my code.  Nothing seems to be working!

Here is what I have -

CSS

```
/*Page Setup*/
.html {height: 100%;}
.body {height:100%;}

.top{
    margin-left:200px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#b41601;
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}
.left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    min-height:100%;
    background:#b41601;
}
.main{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

These divs are all placed within the body (obvious I guess).  I added the height CSS to 'body' and 'html' after reading through some previous solutions but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Image of scrolled down window as site isn't online.  Bar on left sitting at 100% original window size

[image: Image of scrolled down window as site isn't online. Bar on left sitting at 100% original window size]

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle so we can see

Comment: Not done it before, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: We need to see your html code as well.

Comment: Try this jsfiddle - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nxn42f7f/) it seems to have nudged the top div down a bit but you can see how the left div doesn't expand into the scroll area.

Is this enough to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your .left `div` css `position: fixed`

```
.left{
    position:fixed;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    background:#b41601;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jldelacruzsantos/qd1rj1LL/

Comment: that way the left div won't scroll, it will be fixed while the rest of the page scrolls

Comment: That's what he wants if i'm not mistaken :)

Comment: That's not what I understood but it's accepted so I guess you're right :)

Comment: Over an hour of reading other threads and this simple thing fixed it!  I'm learning more every day.  Thanks John.

@FabioG The left div doesn't actually need to scroll, it just needs to be visible while the rest scrolls.  It has a menu in it which will always be seen using this solution.

Comment: And you can take out `float: left` and `min-height: 100% ` as they are'nt needed and will likely confuse user when looking at it.

Comment: @LGSon Done. Thanks mate

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz Please take out `float: left` and `min-height: 100%` as they are'nt needed and will likely confuse next users when looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a wrapper containing  all the rest with `position: relative`

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL61L0w2/)

Comment: I see this causes the left div to scroll along with the rest.  I'll definately remember this even if it isn't what I currently need.  Thanks for the work.

Answer (score 0):

As `position: fixed` sometimes can act quirky on phones and tablets, this solution has an added `wrap` to the `top`/`main`, which will scroll when it overflows, and to avoid a scroll on the body, its margin is set to 0.

```css
html, body {height:100%; margin: 0}

.wrap{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.top{
    margin-left:200px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#b41601;
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}
.left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    background:#b41601;
}
.main{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">TOP</div>
  <div class="main">
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
    MAIN<br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```